# checking attribute of a tag with a regex using rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, rspec

I'm fairly new to Rspec so apologies if this is a really simple question:

I want to check that there is some link on the page that has a link to a pdf.

Essentially something along the lines of:

```
rendered.should have_selector :a[href=~/\.pdf/]
```

but I'm getting the error undefined variable or method href.

Is there someway to do:

> attribute.should =~ /regex/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using has_selector should do a substring match for you, so you could always try doing something like this:

```
response.should have_selector("a", :href => ".pdf")
```

Comment: is that true for all attributes? I'm having a problem where I have a match but not a complete match and that gives me error.

Comment: I can verify that this seems not to be case. Take for example, I'm using `datetime_select :campaign_start` and I would like to check for the select's presence in rspec. I thought that `response.should have_selector("select", :name => "campaign_start")` should do the trick but it doesn't. I'm still looking for other solutions.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [CSS3 Substring matching attribute selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-substrings) for this case.

```
rendered.should have_selector 'a[href$=.pdf]'
```